# Is it possible for typescript to continue to infer the exact values of an array marked "as const" after it goes through an operation?

Tags: typescript

Say I have this array:

```
const myArray = ["foo", 3.14, true] as const;
```

Typescript will infer that this array is:

```
readonly ["foo", 3.14, true]
```

So it knows exactly what the array is.

I'm trying to increase my knowledge of typescript, and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to perform a generic operation on this array `as const` and preserve typescript's inference of these values.

For example, is it possible to write a function in typescript called `convertNumbersToStrings()` that accepts any readonly array as an argument and outputs another readonly array where, if I pass my `as const` array, typescript can infer that the result is: `["foo", "3.14", true]`?

Comment: Updated my answer based on @Blackhole's comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (thanks to @Blackhole for correcting my Sunday night brain failure).

```js
type ConvertedNumbersToStrings<Arr extends readonly any[]> = {
    [Index in keyof Arr]:
        Arr[Index] extends number ? `${Arr[Index]}` : Arr[Index]
}
```

[TS playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgewHYDcoCcRQCYDkCuAtgEYYDOAKggMojoCWSA5mQDwCC66MUAHlkmxkY6KAENsyADZgYYpGADaAXQB8MALwwA3sBj6YigJKC+MRjADWUMAgBmMTumUAuPQY9Pjp3sp78oQWEkIlJuAH4YAAMAEm0vE2w+ZQBfKJgXRy5vJN9gFOBgO3wkAGMQemQYUuQ0TAIScipaBmY2J38BIRFxSSQZOQUVVQAKMS5MpwBKd31MxFQMLDxQppo6RhYOLlVgXQ9REHx0JDkuADpCMQgR3k11cGh7GDuNN5gAIhDG9A+YSN45xA61aTBGUwyLwhYmECzqywaYUoIM27R2AG58oUakgyCAYIQwE4xLItIoPnYEAgPgAaGAAZnOAEYACx0uj4KB+GHVZB4zE4vEwBD4fFaHHwxFrFqokaE4lgKaYgD0ypgjygzxFYp6EmksnJlOpdI+jNZtPV6E5yiAA)

Mapped tuples tend to need a little help and the implementation is rough, but you'll get a result:

```js
function convertNumbersToStrings<Arr extends readonly any[]>(arr: Arr)
    : ConvertedNumbersToStrings<Arr>
{
    return arr.map(x =>
        typeof x === "number" ? x.toString() : x
    ) as ConvertedNumbersToStrings<Arr>;
}

const myArray = ["foo", 3.14, true] as const;
const out = convertNumbersToStrings(myArray);
// typeof out = readonly ["foo", "3.14", true]
```

Without the return type annotation, `out`'s type is inferred as `any[]`.

Comment: `StringToNumber` isn't possible, but `NumberToString` is easy, unless I misunderstand something: `type NumberToString<E extends number> = \`${E}\`;`

Comment: @Blackhole [`StringToNumber`](https://tsplay.dev/m3xq2W) is certainly possible.

Comment: @vera. Oh, yeah, I forgot about the `infer` keyword. Thanks for the heads-up!